# How can I get an infinite callhistory in CyanogenMod 10.0?

Tags: calls, logging, call-history

I would like to have all calls I ever called or called me in the history.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does the current call history have a limit? Sorry, I don't have CM here. [Just asking]

Answer (score 0):

Try [BearContact](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skzeng.beardialer) on Google Play. It can keep unlimited call logs.